# does the regularized heat kernel have the semigroup property?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, convolution, heat-equation, stochastic-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators

Consider the heat kernel on the 2D-torus

$$
K(t,z-z_1):= \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}^2} \exp\Big(-(1-4\pi^2|m|^2)t +2\pi i m \cdot (z-z_1)\Big)
$$

It satisfies the semigroup property
$$
K(t_1+t_2,z_1-z_2)=\int_{\mathbb{T}^2} K(t_1,z_1-z) K(t_2,z_2-z) dz
$$
Let now $\rho_\epsilon$ a mollifier and consider the regularized kernel $K * \rho_\epsilon$.

I'm expecting this new kernel to satisfy the semigroup property as well, but doing the calculation I have
$$
I:=\int_{\mathbb{T}^2} \int \int K(t_1-\tau_1,z_1-z-x_1) \rho_\epsilon(\tau_1,x_1) K(t_2-\tau_2,z_2-z-x_2) \rho_\epsilon(\tau_2,x_2) d\tau_1 dx_1 d\tau_2 dx_2 dz
$$
By using the semigroup property of $K$ and Fubini we have

$$
I=\int \int K(t_1+t_2-\tau_1-\tau_2,z_1-x_1-z_2+x_2) \rho_\epsilon(\tau_1, x_1) \rho_\epsilon(\tau_2,x_2) d\tau_1 dx_1 d\tau_2 dx_2=K *\rho_\epsilon *\rho_\epsilon(t_1+t_2,z_1-z_2)
$$
This is strange as $K * \rho_\epsilon$ should be the kernel associated to the regularized stochastic heat equation *i.e*
$$
\partial u^\epsilon=\Delta u^\epsilon + \xi^\epsilon
$$
where $\xi^\epsilon := \xi * \rho_\epsilon$ is the regularization of the white noise and so it should satisfy the semigroup property. Did i have done some mistakes in my calculation?

Comment: what is the regularised heat equation?

Comment: @CalvinKhor I corrected it. It is the kernel associated to the (pathwise) solution of the stochastic heat equation with regularized noise

Comment: OK. I don't know any S(P)DEs, but I believe a semigroup should satisfy $K_t |_{t=0} = \delta_0$ or something like this. This is also violated by your $K * \rho_\epsilon$